# Create several HTML email signatures for company based on a table of information

Tags: excel-formula, html-email

I am tasked with updating a companies email signature for everyone in the company. I have created the HTML email signature and wrote it on Codepen. I have all of the information to create each email signature but I am wondering how I could create all of the email signatures based on my Excel file (Name, Phone Number, a link to the persons' photo, etc).

How do companies create multiple HTML email signatures based on a table of information?

Comment: I would export cvs and iterate over it in search of specific user information. Nothing spectacular :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an Excel question, unless you are a programmer.

Setup your Excel file with the HTML in it, and name, phone etc. interspersed as required, and use CONCATENATE(a1,b1,c1,...) to join it all up.

[image: Excel Concatenation]

Comment: Great solution!